# NodeJS async/await class mysql/mariadb

Tags: mysql, node.js, class, asynchronous, async-await

I tried to something I thought would be simple using: nodejs 8.6, MariaDB, MySQL2/promise and classes.  But it does not work:

Here is the simple example:

```
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');

class mySQLClass {
    constructor() {
        this.mysqlConn = null;
    }

    async initialize() {
        try {
            this.mysqlConn = await mysql.createConnection({
                host: 'localhost',
                user: 'root',
                password: '',
                database: 'myschema'
            });

            console.log('intialize complete - createConnection successful: ');

        } catch (err) {
            console.log('initialize failed: ' + err);
        }
    }

    async showMeSomeData() {
        try {
            const [rows, fields] = await this.mysqlConn.execute('select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = \'information_schema\'');
            console.log('data: ' + rows);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('showMeSomeData failed: ' + err);
        }
    }

}

const test = new mySQLClass();

test.initialize();

test.showMeSomeData();
```

When I run the program, it fails with:

> showMeSomeData failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of null
>
> intialize complete - createConnection successful

So, it appears that initialize() is not completing before showMeSomeData() is executing.  I thought that await would allow this to work correctly?

Am I missing something?
Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At the top level, async functions still return a promise. You would have to do:

```
const test = new mySQLClass();

test.initialize().then(() => {
  test.showMeSomeData();
});
```

To get YOUR code to work, you'd have to hide an extra promise in your class:

```
async initialize() {
    let done, fail;
    this.initializing = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        done = resolve;
        fail = reject;
    });

    try {
        this.mysqlConn = await mysql.createConnection({
            host: 'localhost',
            user: 'root',
            password: '',
            database: 'myschema'
        });

        done();

        console.log('intialize complete - createConnection successful: ');

    } catch (err) {
        console.log('initialize failed: ' + err);
        fail();
    }
}

async showMeSomeData() {
    await this.initializing;
    try {
        const [rows, fields] = await this.mysqlConn.execute('select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = \'information_schema\'');
        console.log('data: ' + rows);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('showMeSomeData failed: ' + err);
    }
}
```

You will still have to use promises at the top level if you want to get data out, but your console.logs will at least happen in-band.

Comment: Thanks.  That resolved the issue.  It does make me question the value of using async/await versus just using promises or callbacks.